Flutter speech-to-text for own vocabulary of words
I am developing a Flutter based application using the speech-to-text package. Our speeches will mainly be the names of medicines which can never be found in the Dictionary. So far I have explored many tutorials and stackoverflow solutions, but none has this particular solution.
User will say the name of a medicine, but flutter speech-to-text does not understand it and either ignores it or returns a more close dictionary word.
To elaborate more, it’s like adding my own vocabulary of words. I have even tried with localisation but could not figure out or get any solution to this problem.
I am stuck up, any solutions to resolve it would be highly appreciated.

If we are talking about the same package speech_to_text, maybe there's no way. It wraps all native systems voice recognition, so there's not a direct way to customize the dictionary. For example:
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech
Analyzing both Android and iOS APIs, they are very limited to download languages and in most cases, infering in some results like Android AlternativeSpan, but I don't think that's the case.
I don't know if you are planning to use only local or cloud Speech to Text recognition, but I would recommend Google Speech-to-Text API.
It's available on googleapis package.
I've also searched for some edge models and could only find https://huggingface.co/openai/whisper-small as tiny version, but not sure how "tiny" it is for a mobile phone.

Thanks! I need this to run locally, because of remote areas where there is no internet.

How are the possibilities of a pre-trained Tensorflow Model and install in Flutter to run offline? Also, I see that Amazon Transcribe has great support for custom vocabulary but probably it cannot be used offline or installed in Flutter app.
